# jquery: context with closures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I got a simple question about jQuery but rather javascript approaches in general...

Is it ok, to do this? :

```
this._checkedTexts.length = 0; // <- array belonging to "me"
var contextCheckedTexts = this._checkedTexts;

$('#valueContainer input:checked').each(function() {
  contextCheckedTexts.push($(this).text());
});
```

Since 'this' points to the element, I am using a closure here to keep additional context for the 'each'-handler around.

Is this the way 'how it's done' or could there be any risk involved using a closure in this way (memoryleak-wise....)?

What other options are there?

I find it very practical - but also I'm always a little worried about introducing reference-count-problems when using closures - which will be hard to find later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but your codes may also be done like this,

```
this._checkedTexts.length = 0; // <- array belonging to "me"

var arr = $('#valueContainer input:checked').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

this._checkedTexts = this._checkedTexts.concat(arr);
```

Comment: Pretty awesome :) I love jQuery more and more... thanks for the hint!! - but still, the question remains: is it ok (and the usual approach) to use closures for context to a function that has the 'wrong' this-pointer?

Comment: yes it's fine to use closures... but if you do it, do it like this, `var self = this;`... so that you can call other properties using `self`. e.g. `self._checkedTexts.push($(this).text());. with that, you already eliminate `var contextCheckedTexts = this._checkedTexts;`...

Comment: ... sounds like a plan - and also if I'm doing it this way every time, there is probably less confusion :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fine as jQuery methods like `each`, `map`, `grep` does not support context by default (there're bound to the current jQuery object). However you can create you own `bind` function that will apply context to functions (but in this case you dontn't have to as you use default context to get the elements text).